# How to extract specific information from raw , unstructured text using NLP and Deep Learning?

Tags: deep-learning, nlp, named-entity-recognition

I have data coming from different sources having similar information like the below example where different sources want to specify the age criteria. Is there a NLP or Deep learning based approach which I can use to extract the age rule as shown below from raw unstructured text.

```
A Criteria
Applicants should be above 21 years of age and up to 65 years or less at the time of maturity.

B Criteria
You are between 25-58 years of age.

C Criteria
Age of the all applicants should be between 21 and 65 .


A Rule
age >=21 AND age <= 65

B Rule
age >=25 AND age <= 58

C Rule
age >=21 AND age <= 65
```

Answer (score 2):

You can create your own named-entity recognition through a pre-trained model like Spacy. https://spacy.io/usage/linguistic-features#section-named-entities

these keywords in your example should be considered as an age entity

```
 above 21 years
 65 years or less
```

try to play its linguistic features to get what you need.
Hope this helps.